# Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined when using Ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am running into the below issue when trying to send transaction details. We are using Tag Manager to fire GA with a secondary tag for to fire transaction details.

> Executing Google Analytics commands.
>   analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("ecommerce:send")
>   analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. 
>   Unknown target: undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Analytics not receiving events (Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212056/google-analytics-not-receiving-events-command-ignored-unknown-target-undefine)