# Google Analytics not receiving events (Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined)

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

So I got my Google Analytics set up via Google Tag Manager. Page views tracking is working fine. But when I try to track any events, the data is just not getting through to Analytics. The event tracking did not work with traditional Analytics code either.

Analytics debug is showing several "Create config had an unknown parameter: x"
and "Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined"

Supposedly this means that there is something wrong with my tracker name. I have tried both default name and custom names.

Might be worth mentioning: Until recently, my site's default URL was wrong in Analytics site preferences, but I'm not sure if that has anything to do with this.

**Analytics debug message:**

```js
Executing Google Analytics commands.
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("create", {2: null, 3: null, 6: "1", 10: false, 11: false, 12: false, 16: false, 17: false, 18: false, 28: false, 32: "UA-1439995-1", 33: false, 34: false, 35: [{fieldName: "cookieDomain", value: "auto"}]}, {name: "gtm5"})
analytics_debug.js:10 Creating new tracker: t0
analytics_debug.js:10 Create config had an unknown parameter: "2"
analytics_debug.js:10 Create config had an unknown parameter: "3"
analytics_debug.js:10 Create config had an unknown parameter: "6"
analytics_debug.js:10 Create config had an unknown parameter: "10"
analytics_debug.js:10 Create config had an unknown parameter: "11"
analytics_debug.js:10 Create config had an unknown parameter: "12"
analytics_debug.js:10 Create config had an unknown parameter: "16"
analytics_debug.js:10 Create config had an unknown parameter: "17"
analytics_debug.js:10 Create config had an unknown parameter: "18"
analytics_debug.js:10 Create config had an unknown parameter: "28"
analytics_debug.js:10 Create config had an unknown parameter: "32"
analytics_debug.js:10 Create config had an unknown parameter: "33"
analytics_debug.js:10 Create config had an unknown parameter: "34"
analytics_debug.js:10 Create config had an unknown parameter: "35"
Executing Google Analytics commands.
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("gtm5.set", "&gtm", "G32NJ6NK7K")
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
analytics_debug.js:10 Executing Google Analytics commands.
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("gtm5.set", "nonInteraction", false)
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
analytics_debug.js:10 Executing Google Analytics commands.
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("gtm5.set", "hitCallback", [function])
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
analytics_debug.js:10 Executing Google Analytics commands.
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("gtm5.send", {hitType: "event", eventCategory: "contact-form", eventAction: "successful-form-submission-mailsent", eventLabel: "362", eventValue: undefined})
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
```

[Analytics debug message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbHVS.png)

Comment: And do you have Google Analytics implemented via the built-in tags or some custom code inside an HTML tag? Can you provide a screenshot of either?

Comment: Analytics is implemented via built-in tags. 

Here's a screenshot of Tag Assistant on my page and GTM Analytics Tag Configuration + GTM preview to see which tags are being fired: [link](https://imgur.com/a/HBcsn)

Comment: Can you show the GA settings?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? GA settings where? Do you mean Site preferences in Analytics?

Comment: In the 2nd of the screenshots you shared (https://imgur.com/a/HBcsn), the variable used as `Google Analytics Settings` (`{UA-XXXXXXX}`)

Comment: Okay, maybe this is what you were asking for: [link](https://imgur.com/a/A4oNv)

Also, thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This is the settings variable - can you also check if you override something in the actual GA tags ? Because in your settings variable you only have default settings that should not cause problems.  In the debug message it looks like a garbled configuration object is passed to the create call (which could e.g., happen if you accidentally pass a GTM variable with an object to the tracker name field).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I have found a solution.

I edited my Universal Analytics tags (Contact Form Submission and GA-Pageview) in GTM by setting tracker names to blank.

(Edit Tag -> Enable overriding settings in this tag -> More Settings -> Advanced Configuration -> Set Tracker Name [True]

I have no idea why I had to do this and if this is a good solution. But now event tracking seems to work.

Comment: Where do you exacly find this 'Edit Tag' option? Inside Google Tag Manager? I mean, do you configure the container or a concrete tag?

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem.  I had set my variable " tracking id" to type google analytics settings, instead of constant. Changing to constant removed this strange create function.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the answer: when you create your tracker initially, although you assign the name `gtm5`, the tracker is assigned the default name `t0`. Therefore when you refer to `gtm5` in the later calls `gtm5.set`, it fails, and that's the error you're getting (`Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined`, `target` being the tracker name you're referring to).

Now what I don't understand, is that the [screenshot you provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xye3x.jpg), the Google Analytics settings look pretty much standard, whereas in the debug, we see custom fields trying to be assigned (`{2: null, 3: null, 6: "1", 10: false`). GA seems confused by that syntax, hence why it ignores your `{name: "gtm5"}` option and assign the default `t0` name.

**Are you sure the [screenshot you provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xye3x.jpg) is related to the debug we see** (for me it doesn't seem like so, the [GTM debug mode](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107056?hl=en) would help you find out).

Comment: The third screenshot here [link](https://imgur.com/a/HBcsn) is from GTM debug console. (Currently can't take any new screenshots since I'm not home.) What is strange, is that I'm not trying to assign any custom names or custom fields to anything.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you have added a Google Analytics Settings variable into a field named “Tracking ID”, either in the tag itself or the settings variable used in the tag.

The field named “Tracking ID” can never have anything else except a string “UA-XXXX-Y” or a variable that returns said string (e.g. Constant, Lookup Table).

The Google Analytics Settings variable doesn’t return “UA-XXXXX-Y” but rather a configuration object. That’s why you see the errors.

Fix the Tracking ID field and your tag will work.